# Possible to get access to SP

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

If I create a store procedure, named test, that contains lots of different columns from many different tables.

I wanna let 20 users to get access to the data with stored procedure via excel.

My question is:
Is it possible to make the user to get access only to the store procedure, test, only? Users shall not have access to table or view. Store procedure test only. I'm using SQL server 2008 R2 standard

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx access to the single stored procedure and no permissions to the table.

```
Grant EXECUTE On [SpName] To [Principal]
```

There is no such concept as a read permissions to a table for a stored procedure. Stored procedure permissions are separate from other objects. If a user has permission to run a stored procedure, they can run it no matter what it does, even if they don't have permission to the underlying objects